# Test that an exception is handled correctly with pytest

Tags: pytest, try-except

I have a block of try-exception code and I want to test if the block works properly? I wonder if there is a way to test this block with a unit test using pylint? This is the snipent I have:

```
   class data_type(Enum):
      SESSIONS = 0
      RUNS = 1

   def find_filter(data_type)
      try:
        if data_type.name == 'SESSIONS':
            return {}
        elif data_type.name == 'RUNS':
            #Filter out rerun jobs
            filter = {
                "filter":{
                    "attName":"is_rerun",
                    "operand":"IN",
                    "@c":".InFilter",
                    "values":["FALSE"]
                }
            }
            return filter
    except AttributeError as erro:
        loghandler.critical('Error in creating count query: {}'.format(erro))
```

I want to test if the data_type is not a valid enum member, the exception catches it before the execution goes to if statement. For example if:

```
find_filter('')
```

is called I like to see that the except AttributeError as erro captures the error and the error is logged.
Is there a way to do that?

PS: I know with pytest.raises() I can test if a raised error is really raised? But as far as I understand pytest.raises() does not work for testing the exception block of a try-exception case.
Any suggestion please?
Thanks.

Comment: This is an implementation detail which you actually shouldn't test - you could instead check that the correct message is logged in this case, and `None` is returned.

Comment: Thank you MrBean Bremen! With your answer I have realized that I have missed to return None in the except part of the code. But just to understand it better by 'This is an implementation detail which you actually shouldn't test' you mean that generally except blocks are not needed to be tested?

Comment: You test inputs, outputs and side effects of functions. If an exception is raised and handled internally, this by itself will in no way effect the environment, so you don't need to test it. As I said - this is an internal implementation detail, relevant is only the outcome (in this case the log and the return value).